# How to integrate MCOM - Magento Commerce Order Management tool to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration

We are struggling with lack of proper documentations for integrating `MCOM - RabbitMq - Magento 2.`

All we have done so far is we have integrated/configured Magento 2 with RabbitMq and RabbitMq queues are generated properly.

1. How to establish connection between MCOM and Magento 2.

This may not be a right place to ask this question, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCOM (as well as RabbitMq) are both EE only features.

AFAIK there's no need to integrate MCOM to Magento 2 as it's supported out of the box.

I suggest you contact the Magento support directly so they can enable MCOM for you on your EE installation.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to integrate into MCOM, previously we had only a RabbitMQ based integration available but we now also have (and prefer you to use) a JSON RPC over HTTP based API.

Essentially the messages are the same, but you communicate via HTTP instead of RabbitMQ.

There's full documentation on the messages available via; https://magento-mcom.github.io/docs/

And some integration guides here; http://documentation.cs.mcom.magento.com/

Just to clarify, MCOM is not an EE "feature", it's a separate Magento product which has an associated license fee and cost attached.

Always best to reach out to one of the MCOM Solution Architects for help with a project, we're friendly!